# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{−k^2/(k-k_0)^2}dk$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I have here the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{−k^2/(\Delta k)^2}dk$, but then $\Delta k$ is equal to $k-k_0$ so this equation becomes
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{−k^2/(k-k_0)^2}dk.$
The first equation is easy because it can be easily transformed into a Dirichlet integral but taking the relationship of $\Delta k$ the equation becomes very hard to solve. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Sure $(k-k_0)^2$ should be in the exponent?

Comment: As you wrote it the integral diverges...

Comment: yes, it is in the exponent.

Comment: It may be true that $\Delta k$ is defined as the difference between $k$ and some other number, but is it possible it's some fixed number?  In that case, there's no need to replace it with $k - k_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Does the function $\exp\left(-k^2/2(k-k_0)^2\right)$ have a limit at $\infty$?